# Telegraf agent configuration to avoid metric buffer overflow

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

After getting some **metric buffer overflow** warning messages, I am trying to understand better how the fundamental agent parameters `interval`, `metric_batch_size`,  `metric_buffer_limit` and `flush_interval` impact each other.

Looking the [specification](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.20/administration/configuration/#agent-configuration), these 3 parameters are defined as:

- **interval** : Default data collection interval for all inputs
- **metric_batch_size** : Telegraf will send metrics to output in batch of at most `metric_batch_size` metrics.
- **metric_buffer_limit** : Telegraf will cache `metric_buffer_limit` metrics for each output, and will flush this buffer on a successful write. This should be a multiple of `metric_batch_size` and could not be less than 2 times `metric_batch_size` .
- **flush_interval** : Default data flushing interval for all outputs. You should not set this below `interval` . Maximum `flush_interval` will be `flush_interval` + `flush_jitter`

What I understand is that

- Data is only written to the output at each `flush_interval` .
- If not all the data can be written, it uses the buffer to store.

What I am not sure to understand is when will the buffered data be written to the output again ? Will it be at next `flush_interval` occurence ?

Thanks in advance for your help on this !

Comment: Question also asked on [Telegraf community](https://community.influxdata.com/t/clarify-telegraf-agent-configuration-to-avoid-metric-buffer-overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered and solved thanks to [Jay_Clifford](https://community.influxdata.com/u/jay_clifford/summary)

> Yes. Data will be sent at the next flush interval.

(cf. [Telegraf community post](https://community.influxdata.com/t/clarify-telegraf-agent-configuration-to-avoid-metric-buffer-overflow/22106/2))